ftp_client_demo example for NUCLEO-F429ZI in Keil uVision problem with server connection
I am trying to run the ftp_client_demo for NUCLEO-F429ZI evaluation board in Keil uVision
that can be found in the Pack Installer for Keil uVision and in here :https://www.keil.arm.com/boards/stmicroelectronics-nucleo-f429zi-revb-8451e6e/projects/
I have managed to compile the code and flash the micro-controller but in the instructions in the abstract.txt file it says that you should

Open main.c and customize the hostname of the FTP server
Set the relevant login and password

elaborates NO further and when I connect the board via comp port and ethernet cable as instructed I see in Realterm(the terminal I used) that some connection has been established as seen here :

Yet when I press "User Button" again as per the instructions to start the FTP test sequence I get this massage :

Does anyone know what server do I have to connect to, what name, what kind of server I didn't find any information about it
